# Sort Gridview based on specific column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a grid view that filled from an slq datasource. The gridview also has an onlad event. This event fills a column with counts that pulled  from a sql query(independently from the sql datasource). How can I sort descending  the gridview based on the results of this specific column that generated from onload event?

Comment: Show your full code and tell people what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

```
  protected void radgvData_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            GridTableView tableView = e.Item.OwnerTableView;
            e.Canceled = true;
            GridSortExpression expression = new GridSortExpression();
            expression.FieldName = e.SortExpression;
            if (tableView.SortExpressions.Count == 0 || tableView.SortExpressions[0].FieldName != e.SortExpression)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Descending)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Ascending;
            else if (tableView.SortExpressions[0].SortOrder == GridSortOrder.Ascending)
                expression.SortOrder = GridSortOrder.Descending;
            tableView.SortExpressions.AddSortExpression(expression);
            radgvData.Rebind();
        }
```

Try this code for sorting

Comment: Thank you for your help how I connect the gridview with this code? My gridview named Gridview1. The name of column that filled from onload is SumofBooks.

Comment: @Equilibrium =  protected void GridView1_SortCommand(object sender, GridSortCommandEventArgs e)

Comment: @Equilibrium = from this code all the column of gridview have take the sorting

Comment: I have error:The type or namespace name 'GridTableView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Comment: R u use telerik gridview or asp grid view ?